# Im using OAUTH2.0 but can pass the review before going live DOCUSIGN

Tags: rest, docusignapi, e-signature

I am in the process of going live in docusign from my developer account, when making the 20 consecutive calls i used Authorize Code Grant Access Token to get the access token but i am not passing the review and getting error "not using oauth 2.0", what should i do?. i have done this process before but it is the first time getting this error

this is the url i am using to authenticate

[image: 1]

the method to pass the review to go live

Comment: This feels like a Docusign support request, not a general programming question especially given no code was shown.

Answer (score 0):

So, it's enough that you made a single bad call, to make all the other good calls irrelevant.

In other words, maybe you did 20 calls with OAuth 2.0, but then you made (for whatever reason) a call using the old legacy auth (X-DocuSign-Authentication header) and that one will fail your review.

You could start with a new IK and change the IK and run the calls again, or you can contact DocuSign Developer support to try to get you an exception.

Comment: Could you tell me which api url does not have those old legacy auth , so i avoid them ?, thanks

Comment: I don't have access to the logs, you'll have to work with support. You could search your code for X-DocuSign-Authentication